# Dict Key Python Issue

Tags: python

I am trying to pass values for each key in a dictionary via a parameter. Below is the code. However, the values are getting substituted with additional double quotes ". Could you please advise what I have been doing wrong?

value1 is being derived from configuration. I am printing them and they are printing fine. value1 and value2 are array of numbers.

```
######## Code Start
    value1 = configuration.value1 
    # value in confirguration['290', '1423', '291']
    value2 = configuration.value1 #
    # value in confirguration['1585', '67', '102095']
    Services = {'mmbtu': value1,
                'mmgal': value2}
    for uom in Services.keys():
        for serviceId in Services[uom]:
            print(serviceId)

####### Code ends
```

when I print Services, below is what it shows and I get serviceId value as [ for 1st occurrence rather than getting 290. I think it is because of double quotes

```
{'mmbtu': "['290', '1423', '291']", 'mmgal': "['1585', '67', '102095']"}
```

When I hardcode the values as below

```
{'mmbtu': ['290', '1423', '291'], 'mmgal': ['1585', '67', '102095']}
```

it works fine and I get serviceId value as 290 for 1st occurrence.

I think its the extra double quotes. Please can you guide me what I am doing wrong and how should I proceed with it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `"['290', '1423', '291']"` is a string. Strings are iterable. You haven't provided a [mcve], and for some reason I can't imagine, you failed to provide the full error message, so we can only speculate, but the message is telling you you are trying to iterate over `None`. Why? Who knows. Again, you must provide a [mcve]. Please see [ask] and the [help]

Comment: Note, the error is unreproducible if I use your code and `{'value1': "['290', '1423', '291']", 'value2': "['1585', '67', '102095']"}` as a value for `self.Services`.

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the question with more details. Sorry about the trouble.

Comment: Please *actually read the links I gave you*. This is absolutely **not** a [mcve]. In any case, now you aren't actually getting an error, you are getting an ouput of `"["`, which is obvious, because your *value is the string `"['290', '1423', '291']`. You are going to have to parse that string. You should probably fix the problem that is causing this to begin with

Comment: Is your dict called `Services`, or `self.Services`?  Those are entirely unrelated names.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` to change your string into a Python list.  I think that's what you really want.

Comment: please ignore self.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Changing the variable from string to list helped.